# OpenMP in Visual C++ 2008 Standard Edition

Tags: visual-studio-2008, openmp

How can I get OpenMP set up in VC++ 2008? The compiler supports it, I believe I am only missing headers/libs. Can I obtain them similar to how the framework SDK can be added to VC++ Express for MFC development?

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable OpenMP support in the C++ project properties (this is a compiler option).

You also need to `#include <omp.h>` in any source file where you are using OpenMP pragmas and/or library calls.  This bit me, as the documentation says the include is only needed when making library calls, but not for using pragmas alone.  But the documentation is wrong.  The `omp.h` header updates the manifest of your executable so the run-time library can be found (vcomp.dll).

Answer (score 0):

Afaik, only professional editions come with OpenMP.

An alternative is to use Cygwin and download the c/c++ development packages (gcc 4.2 is the default i think and it'll have OpenMP supported)

Comment: That's a horrible alternative :) And not really workable on this project really, which is strongly VS-based. I've _used_ OMP on VS before (2005 express probably), in fact I wrote articles about it... so I'm confused how I managed to get it to work before!

Answer (score 0):

The [Windows SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=4377f86d-c913-4b5c-b87e-ef72e5b4e065&displaylang=en) and [WDK](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/DevTools/WDK/WDKpkg.mspx) have traditionally come with the C/C++ compilers for the various platforms. These compilers often have features enabled that do not come with the express versions of VS.

Two such features used to be included:

- Support for OpenMP
- Support for PREfast

(I say all this in the past tense because it's been awhile since I've installed a Windows DK.)

So it's easy enough to get the compiler for free. The trick will then be to replace VS's `cl` with the appropriate one from the dev kit.